# jshint throwing TypeError in gulp task when it is clearly defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, task, jshint

I'm trying to run a jshint on some JS files, but for some reason am getting an error I don't understand.

```
//(node v4.2.2)
var jshint = require('jshint');
gulp.task('hint', function(){
  return gulp.src('./app/**/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});
```

> [11:40:09] Starting 'hint'...
>
> [11:40:09] 'hint' errored after 7.08 ms
>
> [11:40:09] TypeError: jshint is not a function

I've been looking at the [releases page](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/releases) and it looks like there were some issues with 2.9.0, but I am getting this same error with both of the release candidates and when reverting to earlier versions. This task was working well a few weeks ago, but it seems like something has broken. Logging `jshint` like this, gives me the string below it.

```
gulp.task('testhint', function(){
  console.log(jshint)
});

//{ JSHINT: { [Function] addModule: [Function], data: [Function], jshint: [Circular] } }
```

I've tried deleting and reinstalling `node_modules` as well to no avail. Why is gulp saying that jshint isn't a function?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jshint):

`NOTE: as of 2.0 jshint must to be installed with gulp-jshint.`

Change the statement to:

`var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');`